# Pass object to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of `<span>` elements that is created dynamically in a JavaScript function. Each `<span>` that is created I want to be clickable and call a function that takes the parameter as object on click.

My problem is when I pass the object I get the error `undefined` for  `objAddQuestion`. How can I pass the object to the function?

```
 for (var j = 0; j < lstQuestions.length; j++) {
    var objAddQuestion = new Object();
    objAddQuestion = lstQuestions[j];
    html += ' <span onclick="addQuestion(objAddQuestion)" class="badge addQ">' +
        ' Add</span>';
}
```

and the function:

```
function addQuestion(obj) {
    //I got error when click
}
```

`lstQuestions` is a list of objects.

Comment: @Roy `addQuestion([object Object])`?

Comment: @Roy, you probably want to add `JSON.stringify`? :)

Comment: @VLAZ - No, because the OP is overwriting it on the line after creation. Looks like it's a string.

Comment: What is `lstQuestions`? Is it a list of strings? Objects? Something else?

Comment: list of objects

Comment: @RawanMansour - Please show us that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said that `lstQuestions` is a list of **objects**. That means you probably don't want to embed the question in an `onclick` attribute handler.

Instead, I'd suggest using modern event handling, not `onclick` attributes. For instance, I'd probably do this by including a question identifier on the `span` and then handling the event with event delegation.

Note: You've tagged your question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but there's no jQuery apparent in your question, so I haven't used it in this first solution. You certainly could, though, and the delegation would be simpler; see under the horizontal line below.

```js
var lstQuestions = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Question 1",
        details: "Details for question 1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Question 2",
        details: "Details for question 2"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Question 3",
        details: "Details for question 3"
    }
];
var html = "";
for (var j = 0; j < lstQuestions.length; j++)
{
    // Include the question ID (or if the list never changes, just use `j`) as a data-* attribute
    var question = lstQuestions[j];
    html += ' <span data-question="' + lstQuestions[j].id + '" class="badge addQ">' +
        question.text +
        ' Add</span>';
}
document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = html;

// Handle clicks on the container
document.getElementById("questions").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Did the click pass through a span.addQ?
    var span = e.target.closest("span.addQ");
    if (span && this.contains(span)) {
        // Yes, get its ID
        var id = +span.getAttribute("data-question");
        // Find the question
        var question = lstQuestions.find(function(q) { return q.id === id; });
        if (question) {
            console.log("Question details: " + question.details);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>
```

---

Using jQuery, you might go with [Rory's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493890/157247) using jQuery's element data cache. But here's the above using jQuery rather than using the DOM directly:

```js
var lstQuestions = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Question 1",
        details: "Details for question 1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Question 2",
        details: "Details for question 2"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Question 3",
        details: "Details for question 3"
    }
];
var html = "";
for (var j = 0; j < lstQuestions.length; j++)
{
    // Include the question ID (or if the list never changes, just use `j`) as a data-* attribute
    var question = lstQuestions[j];
    html += ' <span data-question="' + lstQuestions[j].id + '" class="badge addQ">' +
        question.text +
        ' Add</span>';
}
$("#questions")
    .html(html)
    .on("click", "span.addQ", function() {
        // Yes, get its ID
        var id = +this.getAttribute("data-question");
        // Find the question
        var question = lstQuestions.find(function(q) { return q.id === id; });
        if (question) {
            console.log("Question details: " + question.details);
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but I have a problem when I click the add if I try to write something inside the span it's not appear ,like this:$(".qText").text(question.QuestionNo); qtext is a nother span I append when click add question

Comment: @RawanMansour - That would be a completely unrelated question. I suggest having a go (`span`s aren't editable unless you add `contenteditable` to them), doing research, etc., and if you can't resolve it, post a new question with a [mcve] of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you can store the object in jQuery's `data` cache on each `span` that you create. Then you can use an unobtrusive delegated event handler to read them back out again when the element is clicked. Try this:

```js
var lstQuestions = [
  { label: 'foo' }, 
  { label: 'bar' }, 
  { label: 'fizz' }, 
  { label: 'buzz' }
];

var spans = lstQuestions.map(function(o) {
  return $('<span />', {
    'class': 'badge',
    'text': o.label
  }).data('question', o);  
})

$('#questions').on('click', '.badge', function() {
  var obj = $(this).data('question');
  console.log(obj);
}).append(spans);
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions"></div>
```

Another alternative would be to store the index of the related object of the array in the data attribute and then use that to retrieve the item from the array when the element is clicked. Either has advantages, it depends on your use case as to which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to generate the `span` elements one by one, then append it to your container

```js
var container    = document.getElementById( 'container' );
var lstQuestions = [
    'Question A'
  , 'Question B'
  , 'Question C'
];

for (var j = 0; j < lstQuestions.length; j++)
{
    var objAddQuestion = lstQuestions[j];
    var span           = document.createElement( 'span' );

    span.onclick = generateClickMethod( objAddQuestion );

    span.classList.add( 'badge', 'addQ' );

    span.innerText = ' Add ';
    
    container.appendChild( span );
}

function generateClickMethod( obj ){
  return function(){
    addQuestion( obj );
  };
}

function addQuestion( obj ){
  alert( obj );
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If object are global try with:

```
function addQuestion(obj) {
    window[obj];
}
```

for local objects try e.g.:

```
function addQuestion(obj) {
    lstQuestions[obj];
}
```

and:

```
for (var j = 0; j < lstQuestions.length; j++) {
    var objAddQuestion = new Object();
    objAddQuestion = lstQuestions[j];
    html += ' <span onclick="addQuestion('+j+')" class="badge addQ">' +
        ' Add</span>';
}
```